# Сортировка массива объектов по тексту который вносится через input. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты, фильтрация

Всем доброго времени суток.
Прошу помочь разобраться с данным вопросом, буду много признателен.

Есть массив объектов

В элементе **someOfElement** есть поле в котором находится текст, который поместили туда ранее. До момента создания не известно, что за текст.
И так же есть еще одно поле **input** в которое вносится текст который будет использоваться для фильтрации.

Вопрос заключается в чем. 
Как отфильтровать список **arr** по тексту, которое вносится в поле **blockFilter__input**?

Код:

> HTML

```
<button class="blockFilter__loop"></button>
<input type="text"class="blockFilter__input">
<ul class="list">
    **здесь выводится массив arr;**
    **пример someOfElement - а**
    <li>
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> JS

```
var arr = [{id:1;el:someOfElement},
           {id:2;el:someOfElement},
           {id:3;el:someOfElement},
           {id:4;el:someOfElement}];
var textValue = document.querySelector('.blockFilter__input').value;
```

Пытался через

```
arrayForSort.el.filter(function(s){return ~s.indexOf(textValue);});
```

Но ничего не получилось. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(s){return s.el.field.value.includes(textValue);});
```

Comment: В консоле выдает ошибку - 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.filterByText